# Java: How to AUTOMATICALLY test a console application that gets input from user

Tags: java, file, testing, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a console application in Java that gets input from the user by 
'Scanner' class. I don't want to enter each time that I test my program the input manually in the console, so I want to put all my inputs in a text file and make the Java program read this text file instead of typing again the inputs.

The way I found to do it is changing the line:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path_to_text_file));
```

Can you recommend another way that doesn't involve changing the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely can't change your code, use [`System.setIn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) to replace the default input stream with one of your choosing.

Be sure always to change the stream back to the original one once you've finished testing - in doing this, you're mutating global state, so you can leave things in a bad state for the rest of your tests.

```
InputStream previousIn = System.in;
InputStream replacement = new FileInputStream(path_to_text_file);
System.setIn(replacement);
try {
  // ... Do your testing.
} finally {
  System.setIn(previousIn);
}
```

Or, change the design of your code so that you [inject the input stream that you depend on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This avoids the mutation of global state, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have this for testing, the best way would be to write a test for this class. Have a look at [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/).

In such a test you could provide a different Scanner to you original class, either by using

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path_to_text_file));`

or you could use a framework like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) in order to fake different user inputs through Scanner and then check whether these inputs produced the correct outputs.